# Directing most MVC actions to a Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have built an MVC project with a Web API Controller.  Instead of using `POST`, `GET` method, I have configured the routes to use actions in my API Controller.

Here is my router config:

```
  var reportRoute = routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "Report",
                         routeTemplate: "api/Report/{controller}/{action}");
  reportRoute.AddRouteToken("Namespaces", new string[] { "Fanex.Athena.Api.Report" });
  reportRoute.RouteHandler = new MyHttpControllerRouteHandler();
```

And here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic MatchWlMatchBetType(BetListMetaModel metaModel)
{
    var uspKey = IsRacing(metaModel.BetType)
        ? "xxxxx"
        : "xxxaaa";

    return GetBetListResult(metaModel, uspKey);
}

[HttpPost]
public dynamic MatchWlOutright(BetListMetaModel metaModel)
{
    const string uspKey = "xxxx";
    return GetBetListResult(metaModel, uspKey);
}
```

I don't know if this code is good or bad.  Am I using the Web API Controller properly?

Comment: Why do you think its not good? I dont think there is any problem with it. Using verbs in Web Api are one proposed way and not a rule.

Comment: Not sure this is a good question for Code Review SE.

Comment: @Kev Thanks for taking a look =)